# Which is better from a Controls perspective, a Stepper or Servo Motor?

Tags: design, stepper-motor, control, servo

I'm designing a system to control the knob on an Air/Oxygen blender based off readings from a Pulse Oximeter. The idea to use a stepper to control the knob/retrofit an existing blender came from [here](http://samy.pl/combobreaker/).

I went with a Stepper motor for the initial prototype mainly because it doesn't require an encoder, and the speed and precision is more than enough for my requirements. I understand the differences in operation, power consumption, torque, etc and the only real argument for a servo over a stepper I see is heat. However this hasn't been an issue while using the driver circuit I selected. I'm about to graduate with an EE degree and am still learning how to use what I've learned to makes these types of design decisions.

Comment: Whatever meets all the requirements and constraints is the best solution.  If price is important a solution that meets all the requirements at the lowest cost is the right one.  Other constraints may be power consumption, development time (time to market), reliability, solution size, etc.  So the right answer depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, servos and steppers both have pros and cons and tend to have slightly different use cases. This means that, in your case, it comes down to personal opinion (this is more of a yes/no, go/no go site)

Having said that. Steppers can be simpler to drive and can hold their position with no power (although their holding torque is much better *with* power in which case they're no better than servos), but have limited top speeds and tend to be a bit jittery - i.e. they don't have really smooth flowing movement (they're called STEPers for a reason). Servos can be really fast (1000's of rpm) but good ones can be quite pricey due to a much more complex control system, although good quality servos can have very fluid motion. But this depends on whether you mean RC servos or real proper AC *Servomotors*.

It's not that one is inherently better than the other, they're just different (like left and right hand drive). RC servos and un-encoder-ed steppers being more or less on par in terms of practicality.

As it sounds like this is a rough 'n' ready project, the distinction is likely a non-issue in your case, so it's going to come down to what *you* feel is appropriate, go with what you know works for as we engineers say: "*Go with what you know*" as "*Good enough is almost always good enough*"

Comment: I wonder if there are any servos with a worm drive as these would hold their position automatically, even when unpowered.

Comment: @Janka Sure, you can put a worm drive on just about anything, but now it's not a bog standard servo anymore so our comparison has to but adjusted accordingly as you could also just as easily put a worm drive on a stepper ;)

Comment: There is a difference. Servos have their gear included and don't do a full turn any more. While steppers are only a bare motor so you have to think about a gear in any case.

Comment: @Janka are we talking RC servos or proper Servomotors? A straight dc motor with an encoder is *still* a servo, even a stepper with an encoder and feedback circuit is a servo. The ones used in RC models are but just one kind of servo. Large CNCs use AC induction Servomotors, they are still servos, but these things can be several kW and can rotate continuously at several thousand RPM. And no, I wouldn't use one of *those* to control an oxygen blender, but it *is* still a servo. The distinguishing feature of a servo is it's control loop, not it's motive section.

Comment: I mused about what the OP thought and yes, I think he want to use a RC servo (or a stepper).